# Can I access a url with dynamic port through ajax call?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

Consider the following code..

```
  $.ajax({
  url: "http://***.*.*.*:9001/jolokia/*",
  dataType:"json",
  async: false
  }).responseText;
```

Can I access a url with dynamic port? Such as, if the port keeps on changing dynamically can the ajax call get the data from that url?

Comment: An ajax call can be made to any particular port, but you have to know which port to send the ajax call to.

Comment: My port changes dynamically as I am using jolokia for converting my jmx beans to json. I am using dynamic port as it gives bind exception when using a particular port.

Comment: You have to know what the port is in order to connect to it.

Comment: Using dynamic port is not the right way of doing it. If you do not know the port , there is no way to call it using ajax or anything

Comment: I know the port but when I agin start my jvm it changes.

Comment: All the comments above are correct. I just wanted to add that, if the "dynamic" port changes that means the request will be sent to a port different from where the page was originally requested, which compounds your problem because your AJAX call now became a cross-origin request, which are handled differently than same-origin requests.

Comment: Okay, thanks all for your valuable inputs.

Comment: According to the documentation, it is possible to specify the listening port when the jvm starts: http://www.jolokia.org/agent/jvm.html
Is this a possible solution in your case?

Comment: @Zibadian No, I know this is a possible case. but that's not what I want. When I specify the port to one jvm, it gets locked to that jvm, whereas when I try to get jolokia started for another JVM it gives bind Exception. That is why I want to keep the port dynamic.